# How to make two shortcuts: Enable+Start service & Disable+Stop any windows service?

Tags: windows, windows-10, cmd.exe, shortcuts, services

But at this time I need only shortcuts for windows update service. I don't keep windows update service running all time but windows store needs windows update service running. I want to enable+start windows update service before opening windows store with shortcut and disable+stop windows update service after closing windows store.

I found some good answers to restart a service here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995847/desktop-shortcut-to-restart-a-windows-service

Any help will be useful for me and people with same need.

**WORKED FOR ME: (windows 10)**

I created two text files & paste those one line code in each (see accepted answer)

I changed those files extension to .bat

I created 2 shortcuts for both files

I edited those 2 shortcuts to run as admin, > right click on shortcut > click "properties" > go to "shortcut" tab > click "advanced" > tick "run as administrator" > OK > OK

INFO: to get any service name. Go to "services" > right click any service > properties > see service name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### How do I enable/start and stop/disable the Windows Update Service from `cmd`?

You can do this using `sc` commands.

- Either assign the commands to a shortcut or add them to a batch file and assign the batch file to a shortcut.
- To do the same with any other service replace `wuauserv` with the service name.

**Enable/Start**:

```
sc config wuauserv start= auto & sc start wuauserv
```

**Stop/Disable**:

```
sc stop wuauserv & sc config wuauserv start= disabled
```

**Example output**:

```
> sc config wuauserv start= auto & sc start wuauserv
[SC] ChangeServiceConfig SUCCESS

SERVICE_NAME: wuauserv
        TYPE               : 20  WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS
        STATE              : 2  START_PENDING
                                (NOT_STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x7d0
        PID                : 1204
        FLAGS              :

> sc stop wuauserv & sc config wuauserv start= disabled

SERVICE_NAME: wuauserv
        TYPE               : 20  WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS
        STATE              : 3  STOP_PENDING
                                (NOT_STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x1
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x7530
[SC] ChangeServiceConfig SUCCESS
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [sc](http://ss64.com/nt/sc.html) - Service Control - Create, Start, Stop, Query or Delete any Windows SERVICE.

Comment: Thanks. I found one thing when the service is automatic + not running, then disable shortcut is not working. Its working when automatic + running

Comment: @BlackFire Ah. That is because the stop fails. Change the `&&` to `&` and it will run the second command even if the first command fails. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @BlackFire No problem. My fault for not thinking about the corner cases ...

Answer (score 4):

On Windows:
- Right click the desktop.
- Select "New->Shortcut" from the menu to create a shortcut.
- Instead of the location of the item, in the "Type the location of the item" dialog box enter your Command Prompt arguments.

Once the shortcut has been created:
- Right click the shortcut to go to "Properties".
- Select "Advanced" option in the "Shortcut" tab and tick "Run as administrator".